# Symfony2 how to allow slug with dashes in routes regex?

Tags: regex, symfony, routes

My route (slug contains dashes!):

```
region:
  pattern: /regione/{slug}-{id}
  defaults: { _controller: SWAItaliaInCifreBundle:Default:region }
```

In Twig template:

```
{% for r in regions %}
    <a href='{{ path('region', { 'slug':r.slug, 'id':r.id }) }}'>{{ r.name }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

I'm getting an **error** about regular expression matching. **Question**: why Symfony2 does not permit dashes in url? How can i specify that my route contains dashes (and it's perfectly fine)?

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Parameter "slug" for route "region" must match "[^/-]+?"
>   ("valle-d-aosta-vallee-d-aoste" given).")

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Slashes are by default forbidden. You can enable them by changing the default requirements. In your case it'd be also good to give requirements for the id as it's separated with dash.

See example below.

```
region:
    pattern: /regione/{slug}-{id}
    defaults:
        _controller: SWAItaliaInCifreBundle:Default:region
    requirements:
        slug: "[a-zA-Z1-9\-_\/]+"
        id: "\d+"
```

Comment: to allow a trailing slash just add a '/' at the end of your pattern. e.g. pattern: /regione/{slug}-{id}/ - then no regex for this is needed in requirements

Comment: the answer below is the right one. this config has both wrong structure and notation

Comment: @coviex that was an old answer/notation. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 6):

This regex works for me. ({id} requirement suggested by Michael)

```
region:
  pattern: /regione/{slug}-{id}
  defaults: { _controller: SWAItaliaInCifreBundle:Default:region }
  requirements:
    slug: "[a-zA-Z0-9-_/]+"
    id: "\d+"
```

Comment: to make it complete, you could add to requirements: id: \d+

Answer (score 0):

if you try this it will throw a error like this:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Parameter "slug" for route "routing_whatever" must match "[a-zA-Z0-9-_/]+" ("Topics/Virtualization Security" given).") in ...
```

as viewed in http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/slash_in_parameter.html
you must use:

slug: ".+"