# Multiple pattern in single symfony routing

Tags: php, symfony, routes

How to make multiple pattern in single Symfony routing?

Normally we have a routing as

```
blog:
    pattern:   /
    defaults:  { _controller: AcmeBlogBundle:Blog:index, page: 1 }
```

Is it possible to have two routing patterns?

Something like

```
blog:
    #Below pattern to match with '/' or '/index'    
    pattern:   {/ , /index}  
    defaults:  { _controller: AcmeBlogBundle:Blog:index, page: 1 }
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Are you using Symfony2? If you are and can use annotations for your routing instead of yml or xml then it's possible to have multiple routes defined along these lines:

```
/**
* @Route("/");
* @Route("/home");
*/
```

Then you don't need to duplicate the action method.

Comment: it's 2017: is there a Symfony3 way to do this with routing.yaml?

Answer (score 27):

The easiest way is to duplicate the block and make 2 routes.

```
blog:
    pattern:   /
    defaults:  { _controller: AcmeBlogBundle:Blog:index, page: 1 }

blog_index:
    pattern:   /index
    defaults:  { _controller: AcmeBlogBundle:Blog:index, page: 1 }
```

So you have the possibility to use both of them in your path if you need it.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706887/symfony2-how-to-allow-slug-with-dashes-in-routes-regex) you can see another post how to use regex in your routing. Perhaps you can write a simple regex, which checks whether **index** is set.

**Edit:**

If you work with annotations, which I prefer, then you can write more than one route over your Controller's Action method. Something like this:

```
/**
* @Route("/");
* @Route("/home");
*/
```

Comment: Does it work with different parameters ? If yes how ?

Answer (score 19):

When using YAML routes you can also use the [node anchors](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2785586) expression syntax to reference an existing route definition.

`&` specifies the first occurrence of an anchor, `*` specifies the anchor to reference, `<<` tells the [Symfony yaml parser](https://github.com/symfony/yaml/blob/2.8/Parser.php#L184) to merge the specified node.

```
blog: &blog
  path: /
  defaults:  { _controller: AcmeBlogBundle:Blog:index, page: 1 }

blog_index:
  <<: *blog
  path: /index

blog_page:
  <<: *blog
  path: /blog
```

---

Alternatively you can use anchors on a [route attribute value](https://github.com/symfony/yaml/blob/2.8/Parser.php#L515).

```
blog:
  path: /
  defaults: &blog_defaults
    _controller: AcmeBlogBundle:Blog:index
    page: 1

blog_index:
  path: /index
  defaults: *blog_defaults

blog_page:
  path: /blog
  defaults: *blog_defaults
```

---

However to prevent poor SEO due to duplicate content, it is recommended to use a [redirect](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/routing/redirect_in_config.html) instead.

```
blog:
  path: /
  defaults: { _controller: AcmeBlogBundle:Blog:index, page: 1 }

blog_index:
  path: /index
  defaults: &blog_redirect
    _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:redirect
    route: blog
    permanent: true

blog_page:
  path: /blog
  defaults: *blog_redirect
```

Comment: Nice… Didn't know about anchors before this post.

Comment: @LeeviGraham count me in too :D

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to john's answer:

I use it a lot with FOSJsRoutingBundle:

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="route_name_1", options={"expose"=true})
 * @Route("/{id}", name="route_name_2", options={"expose"=true})
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
```

This way I have one method and two routes.

Just remember to set default $id value:

```
public function indexAction($id = null)
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Symfony 5.2 using attributes:

```
#[
    Route('/', 'app_home'),
    Route('/home', 'app_home_alt')
]
```