# Symfony2 Multiple Routes for Single Controller

Tags: symfony, routes, definition

Is it possible to define multiple routes of same controller in a single definition?

For Example:

I want to have a single definition for

```
/, /about, /privacy-policy
```

using something like

```
_home:    
    pattern:   {/ , /about, /privacy-policy}  
    defaults:  { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Home:index, about, privacy_policy }
```

I don't want to define multiple routes in separate definition as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363103/multiple-pattern-in-single-symfony-routing).

**EDIT**: This is my source code:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        /*
         * The action's view can be rendered using render() method
         * or @Template annotation as demonstrated in DemoController.
         *
         */
        return $this->render('AcmeDemoBundle:Home:home.html.tpl');
    }
    /**
     * @Route("/about")
     */
    public function aboutAction()
    {
        return $this->render('AcmeDemoBundle:Home:about.html.tpl');
    }    
}
```

This is the source code of routing.yml

```
_home:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Home:index }
_welcome:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Welcome:index }
_demo_secured:
    resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Controller/SecuredController.php"
    type:     annotation

_demo:
    resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Controller/DemoController.php"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /demo
```

Comment: How about using annotations as suggested in the link you posted? This is AFAIK the only way...

Comment: I tried using that but got error "No route found for "GET /about"", Can you tell me what i had missed. Even for my another method "index" i also get error "[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Route" in method Acme\DemoBundle\Controller\HomeController::indexAction() was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?"

Comment: It is part of an optional bundle called [SensioFrameworkExtraBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/index.html) and the configuration for this particular feature can be found here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html (don't forget the `use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;` statement at the beginning of your controller)

Comment: I have added my code, after using that extra route controller still /about page not working and getting same error "No route found for "GET /about""

Comment: You can have multiple path pointing to the same Controller:Action. However, you can not have the same path pointing to different Controllers:Actions. So you should remove `@Route("/")` on your `indexAction()` or on `aboutAction()`. Have you [activated the annotations in your `routing.yml`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html#activation)?

Comment: Again no luck as i removed @Route("/") from aboutAction

Comment: Can you post the full `routing.yml`?

Comment: You nowhere tell the routing system to look into your `HomeController` to get the route. you should have the same than `_demo` for example but with `resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Controller/HomeController.php"`

Comment: Dont mind, It is resolved as i was missing one thing that to activate Annotation i had to write some code in /app/config/routing.yml too as suggested by @Leo Benoist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't declare name to your route annotation symfony generate one. ("A route defined with the @Route annotation is given a default name composed of the bundle name, the controller name and the action name." from http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html)

By declaring multiple route symfony generate one name (if you don't precise your name) witch probably override your others route by keeping the first.

You could try to test by making a random name to every of your routes in your annotation.

Last thing is to don't forget you root routing file by adding a link to your bundle like this example from the documentation.

```
blog:
    resource: "@SensioBlogBundle/Controller"
    type:     annotation
```

Comment: i simply want to define multiple routes in a single definition having comma separated or any other way (like annotations suggested by @cheesemacfly) However i am still facing issues using annotations. Can you please suggest on that

Comment: If you don't declare name to your route annotation symfony generate one. ("A route defined with the @Route annotation is given a default name composed of the bundle name, the controller name and the action name." from http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html) By declaring multiple route symfony generate one name (if you don't precise your name) witch probably override your others route by keeping the first. You could try to test by making a random name to every of your routes in your anotation.

Comment: It Worked Now !!! Many thanks for your response. You may want to update your answer saying about activating routing in /app/config/routing.yml and using annotations so i would upvote it and accept as a right answer.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't sure it will help you. But happy you find your solution :).

Answer (score 2):

[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Template" in method Debril\RssAtomBundle\Controller\YOURController::indexAction() was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?

Must add two use in YOURController:

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
```