# Symfony2 character between parameters in route

Tags: symfony

So I have this route

`path: /view/{category}-{subcategory}`

And I'm trying to render this route in my twig

`href="{{ path('my_route', {category: cat.slug, subcategory: sub.slug }) }}"`

But symfony is throwing me this error

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Parameter "category" for route "my_route" must match "[^/-]++" ("food-cheap" given)

Isn't it supossed to auto generate the `-` character as I'm setting the real parameters? If I change `-` to `/` it works, but i don't want to use a slash because it's not a URI inside  `category`.

It does also work if I use this

`requirements:
    category: ".*"`

But using slugs (as it's the point of this) for the parameters, goes crazy.

For example
`category: something`
`subcategory: super-size`

URI would be `/view/something-super-size` but Symfony2 says that

`category = something-super`

and

`subcategory = size`

Because everything has `-` and it doesn't know where to stop in the regex pattern.

I've found a strange behaviour...

If I manually type the URL

`http://localhost/view/something-super-size`

It goes correctly to it's controller, without problems and **without using requirements** so maybe the problem is at the `{{ path() }}` method...

Comment: Of couse not! Generating route path Is up to you. Symfony will not generate any `-` char. Your regex should be: `^\/view\/(\w+\-\w+)` or just `/view/{slug}` and in twig:  `path('my_route', {category: cat.slug ~ "-" ~ sub.slug })`

Comment: Using my answer, the dash is auto-generated using the `path` method.

Answer (score 1):

To make your route working with a dash as segments separator, declare your route like this :

```
my_route:
    path: /view/{category}-{subcategory}
    defaults:
        _controller: YourBundle:Controller:method
    requirements:
        category: "[a-zA-Z1-9\-_\/]+"
```

Now the dash will be automatically added between your params when use
`href="{{ path('my_route', {category: cat.slug, subcategory: sub.slug }) }}"`

**EDIT**

To be more precise, with the given regexp, the dash will be considered as uri segment separator, and will not be part of a parameter.
Parameters are intact (doesn't contain the `-`) and when you generate the url with the `path` method, the `-` will be automatically added between the parameters. The regexp just make it working.

[See it in action](http://prntscr.com/a0jevh)

Comment: I don't think category should match `[a-zA-Z1-9\-_\/]+` since `-` is the separator between the two expressions

Comment: Tried and it works, the dash is automatically added between params when generate the url in template, and is accessible using something like /view/1-2 . see http://prntscr.com/a0jevh

Comment: @chalasr Yea, but it's supossed to detect the `{category}` as a parameter, and the `-` just a URL element, like the dash `/`. It detect's the dash as a URI separator, why not `-`? `requirements` works as you say, that's why I used `.*` for `category` but... I don't think it's correct to use it, as the `-` is not a part of the parameter

Comment: As you can see in my screenshot, the `-` is not part of the parameter, just a separator between the params, and is auto-generated by the `path` method exactly as you need (unless I misunderstood your question), and same as the `/` by default. Try and see, your category param will be intact and it will not contains `-`. This alternative solved this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706887/symfony2-how-to-allow-slug-with-dashes-in-routes-regex

Comment: Well, I've tried and, for example I give this category: `something` and a subcategory `super-size`

using your answer, I get this in my request
`category = something-super`
`subcategory = 'size'`

You can test it youserlf.

My URI parameters ARE SLUGS, not id's, so the route can't evaluate what's the parameter and what the separator... because everything has a '-'  in its value, among the separator

Comment: Ok, your case is very specific and the router cannot differentiate the dash in your slug and the separator. Thank you for taking the time to try.