# An exception has been thrown during

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I try set parameters in path twig but I have this error:

[image]

code twig:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
                                        <thead class="text-primary">
                                            <th>Subject</th>
                                            <th>Actions</th>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            {% for x in list%}
                                            {% set f = x.message_id|replace({'<': ''}) %}
                                            {% set rgb = f|replace({'>': ''}) %}

                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>{{x.subject}}</td>
                                                    <td><a href="{{path('getmessage', {'idmsg' : x.message_id })}}"><i class="material-icons">assignment turned in</i>{{rgb}}</a><td>
                                                </tr>
                                            {%endfor%}
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
```

for exemple this is content x.message_id :

> 28e734a78098f2fd.1517587174839.110275113.10011258.en.745ebf318445de15@google.com

when i copie this value and set to idmsg is work:

> 'idmsg': '28e734a78098f2fd.1517587174839.110275113.10011258.en.745ebf318445de15@google.com'

but when i try :

> 'idmsg': x.message_id
>   with this does not work

code routing:

```
getmessage:
path:     /getmessage/{idmsg}
defaults: { _controller: ContextBundle:Default:getMessages }
```

how to resolve this error

Comment: show your routing code

Comment: @habibun i update my answer and i add routing

Comment: did you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706887/symfony2-how-to-allow-slug-with-dashes-in-routes-regex  OR https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/slash_in_parameter.html